# Boost Locale boundary analysis doesn't work with char16_t

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, unicode, boost-locale

I'm trying to use `boost::locale::boundary::segmant_index` to analyse boundaries in a string consisting of `char16_t` symbols. But the following error occurs during compilation (Boost 1.54, GCC 4.8.1):

```
invalid use of incomplete type 'const class boost::locale::boundary::boundary_indexing<char16_t>
```

UPD: here's the example

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

int main() {
    std::basic_string<char16_t> s;
    boost::locale::boundary::segment_index<std::basic_string<char16_t>::iterator> m(boost::locale::boundary::word, s.begin(), s.end());
}
```

Comment: Did you include `<boost/locale/boundary/facets.hpp>`?

Comment: I've tried including it, this doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC's support of char16_t/char32_t is broken. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/locale/doc/html/status_of_cpp0x_characters_support.html

Comment: It seems that this is the explanation, although they write about GCC 4.5, not 4.8.

Comment: The problem is libstdc++ that lacks support of appropriate `std::locale::facets`.